# MYSQL Joins with CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, join

Im running into an error and I cant seem to find the answer from the googling im doing.

what im trying to do is join 3 tables and only display the results when computers are in the 1st and 3rd tables. I also need to join it with the second table that has most the info. The problem im running into is my third left join is not connecting. SelOrder & SelUnit come from some variables pulled from the page url.

```
SELECT * 
FROM admins.computers 
LEFT JOIN admins.users ON admins.computers.`lastuser` = dmins.users.`userid` 
LEFT JOIN vulnerability.$SelOrder ON admins.computers.`cName` =  
                     vulnerability.$SelOrder.`cName` 
WHERE admins.users.`Org` like '$SelUnit' 
ORDER BY admins.computers.`cName` ASC
```

The error im getting is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '-093 ON admins.computers.`cName` =
>   vulnerability.MS15-093.`cName` WHERE admins.' at line

Comment: What is in $SelOrder and do you have a table with that name?A possible fix is to use backticks for ``$SelOrder``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message, along with your question, makes it clear that your `$Selorder` variable has the value

```
  MS15-093
```

You're trying to use that value as a column name. But MySQL sees the hyphen as a subtraction sign, then fails to make sense of the result. To use a column with that kind of name you must escape it in backticks.  So, try this:

```
JOIN vulnerability.`$SelOrder` 
     ON admins.computers.`cName` = vulnerability.`$SelOrder`.`cName`
```

For even greater safety, confine your column names to alphanumeric and underscore characters.